# Showing Ansii text color in ubuntu terminal with Colorama

Tags: python, colorama

trying to run Colorama module in Ubuntu terminal python3. Runs fine in Thonny IDE but not in terminal or IDLE. Ubuntu says Colorama is installed?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "colorama.py", line 1, in <module>
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
  File "/home/simon/Documents/python/RPG/colorama.py", line 1, in <module>
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
  ImportError: cannot import name 'Fore' from partially initialized module 'colorama' (most  likely due to a circular import) (/home/simon/Documents/python/RPG/colorama.py)
```

Comment: don't name your file `colorama.py`